# MySQL solution for using CASE WHEN with another CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, case

I'm having troubles with the following query structure (I can't run it because I don't know how to do it).Simple form of it goes like this:

```
SELECT a,b,
 CASE WHEN a=x AND b=y THEN "Something"
 ELSE "Something Else"
 END AS "1st Case",
 CASE WHEN "1st Case"= "Something" THEN "Something New"
 ELSE "Other"
 END AS "2nd Case"
FROM table1
```

I thought of CTE but I can't use it with our server version. I thought of sub-query but don't know how to reference my custom column (result of "1st Case") in outer query.

Please help me with this, I guess, simple issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select x.*, CASE WHEN 1stCase= 'Something' THEN 'Something New'
 ELSE 'Other'
 END AS '2nd Case' from
(SELECT a,b,
 CASE WHEN a=x AND b=y THEN 'Something'
 ELSE 'Something Else'
 END AS 1stCase from table1)x
```

Comment: Thank you! This is and elegant solution but let's say I have a GROUP BY at the end of the sub-query and MAX in the SELECT part. Should I do the same for outer query?

Comment: yes, you've to do this in subquery, as outer query fetch data from subquery

Comment: I will, but to be clear, every aggregation function that is done on one query (inner or sub-query) should be done on the other(s) query (outer query), right?

Comment: no, if aggregation done in inner query and no need to do it in outer query., that is for sure. But yes it will be based on your scenario.. If you explain your scenario then I could tell you how to do that and what will be the logic

Comment: Yes, just checked that by comparing count of rows between inner query being the single query and the statement structure with outer query. Thanks!